# Reading drug data from nested JSON

Tags: angular

I am facing a problem reading data from nested JSON and loading to a ngx_table.
My JSON looks like:

```ts
[
  {
    "Patientage": 29,
    "Patientname": "Moran",
     "Drugs": [
        {
            "DrugName": "Dolo",
            "Dosage": "150 mg daily",
            "MedicationDuration": "3 years",    
            "MedicationType": "Current"
        },
        {
            "DrugName": "Paracetamol",
            "Dosage": "200 mg daily",
            "MedicationDuration": "2.5 years",  
            "MedicationType": "Current"
        }
        ],
        "Reactions": [
        {
            "Start Date": "10-10-2017",
            "End Date": "15-10-2017"   

        }
        ]
  }
```

]

My `AppComponent.ts`:

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor (private httpService: HttpClient) { }
  arrCase : object [];
  Drugs : object [];
  Drug :  string[] ;

  ngOnInit () {

    this.httpService.get('./assets/Case.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.arrCase = data as object [];  // FILL THE ARRAY WITH DATA.
        console.log(this.arrCase);
         this.Drugs = data["Drugs"] ;
        console.log(this.Drugs)
         this.Drug = this.Drugs["DrugName"];
        console.log(Drug);

      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Am not able to obtain list of Drugs or individual drug from list of Drugs (response messages are not printed to console).

My console(1) msg :

[console.log(this.arrCase)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWPoC.png)

30/05/2018:
Am organizing Drugs to a data service / later using same for CRUD on a MatTable.

```ts
export class DataService {
  private readonly API_URL = './assets/Case.json';
  dataChange: BehaviorSubject<Drug[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Drug[]>([]);
  // Temporarily stores data from dialogs
  dialogData: any;
  Drugs : object [];
  constructor (private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  get data(): Drug[] {
    return this.dataChange.value;
  }
  getDialogData() {
    return this.dialogData;
  }
  /** CRUD METHODS */
  getAllDrugs(): void {
    this.httpClient.get<Drug[]>(this.API_URL).subscribe(data => {
      let res = data[0];    
      this.Drugs = res['Drugs'];    
      // this.dataChange.next(data) 
      this.dataChange.next(this.Drugs)
      console.log(this.Drugs)      
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log (error.name + ' ' + error.message);
     });

  }
```

pls note, this.dataChange.next(data) is necessary to load drugs to table  and it worked with simple json (when my json had only drugs, No reaction or patient info).
When I have nested JSON, we can obtain Drugs in **this.Drug** as coded. Subsequently how 
to use "this.Drugs" with datachange.next ?  - pls guide me.
Thanks 
Asha

Comment: Can you add the ouput of  console.log(this.arrCase); to the question

Comment: data is an **array**. Arrays don't have any property called Drugs. They have elements, indexed from 0. In your case, the first element of this array (we don't know about the others that you didn't post), has a property named Drugs. Do yourself a favor and stop using any or object. Define an interface matching the structure of the JSON objects in the array, and use that as the type of your array.

Comment: Updated with console msg ..

Answer (score 1):

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    arrCase: object [];
    Drugs: object [];
    Drug: string[];
    constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.httpService.get('./assets/Case.json').subscribe(
            data => {
                this.Drugs = this.getDrugs(data);
            },
            (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
     }

    getDrugs(data):any {
       return data.map((item)=>item.Drug));
    }
}
```

by getDrugs method you can get drug list;

please place the service in another file which is a angular service.

hope it help.